# Why is 403 error page from WEB-INF not shown?

Tags: tomcat

In web.xml, when I change this:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/unauthorized.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

to this:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/unauthorized.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

the page is not shown anymore.

*Both files exist and are the same*, and pages for other error types work fine with WEB-INF.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Files inside the WEB-INF are protected from direct access by client. It is defined in the [JavaEE specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html). So when you put the files under the WEB-INF folder they become inaccessible. So it is better to put these(static) files outside of the WEB-INF directory, if you need direct access to them.

Note : You could put files that should be protected from direct access by client under the WEB-INF folder though.

eg : WEB-INF/jsp/protected.jsp

To elaborate on your comment below.

You could map the 403 error page with a controller mapping like below.
Here you will have a common exception.jsp page with different massages depending on the error code which is located inside WEB-INF folder.

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

    /** Holds key for access denied exception. */
    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED = "COMMON.EXCEPTION.403";

    /** Holds return model attribute ACCESS_DENIED. */
    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED_ATT = "accessDenied";

    /** Holds return model PAGE ACCESS_DENIED. */
    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED_HTM = "/accessDenied.htm";

    /** Holds return page of exception. */
    private static final String EXCEPTION = "exception";


    /**
     * Handle access denied exception and display proper message.
     * 
     * @param model - ModelMap
     * @return the name of the view.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = ACCESS_DENIED_HTM, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDenied(ModelMap model) {

        String message = new ErrorMsgLoader().getErrorMessage(ACCESS_DENIED);
        model.addAttribute(ACCESS_DENIED_ATT, message);
        return EXCEPTION;
    }


}
```

Your error mappings in web.xml will be like below.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/accessDenied.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

In the above code, I used the Spring MVC based handler mappings to views. But you could do the same with simple Servlet mapping in case if you are not using any frameworks in your application.

Comment: I don't need direct access, the only access I need is as an error from web.xml, and it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. When you put the error page outside of WEB-INF directory it works, because they are available for direct access by client.If you need to keep the files inside WEB-INF, then you have to go through a request handler to get to the resource.